# How to specify native table fields and a foreign table field during an insert?

Tags: postgresql

Suppose the following:

```
create table member (
    id serial primary key,
    member_name varchar(55),
    role_ids bigint[] not null
);

create table role (
    id serial primary key,
    role_name varchar(55) unique
);

insert into role values (1, 'admin'), (2, 'common');
```

I can create an admin `member` like this:

```
insert into member (role_ids)
select ARRAY[id] as role_id from role where role_name = 'admin';
```

But how can I specify other fields, like `member_name` as well?

I've tried this:

```
insert into member (member_name, role_ids) values('test member', role_ids)
select ARRAY[id::bigint] as role_id from role where role_name = 'admin';
```

But this throws an error, `error at or near select`

Comment: WIth what looks like your preferred syntax: `insert into member (member_name, role_ids)
select 'test_member', ARRAY[id::bigint] as role_id from role where role_name = 'admin';`. With that said, I advise you against using arrays as a column type in a table. I do not know of a use case where it works better than a solution that does not use one.

Comment: One example illustrating the above warning is: how would you manage deletion from the `role` table? Choosing exactly how the DB must behave is super easy (and portable!) using a foreign key but with your array, you get the worst of both worlds: no protection against unwanted deletion (`ON DELETE NO ACTION`), no cleaning of the child table if it happens (`ON DELETE CASCADE`) and no "disconnection" of the child record to its "parent" (`ON DELETE SET NULL`). I hope I do not need to explain why it is bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case I would probably choose to use a nested `SELECT` inside the `VALUES`, to emphasize that this is a lookup that you expect to succeed and return only one value:

```
insert into member (member_name, role_ids)
values('test member',
    (select ARRAY[id] from role where role_name = 'admin'));
```

This wouldn't work if you were selecting more than one column in your select. Another solution would be to just use `SELECT` and no `VALUES`, because nothing stops you from returning literal values in your `SELECT`. You don't name the columns in the select for your insert, instead you order them to match the order of the columns in the insert:

```
insert into member (member_name, role_ids)
select 'test member', ARRAY[id] from role where role_name = 'admin';
```